# Différence entre prédiction et prévision — Difference between prediction and forecasting

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, synonymes

Tout ou presque est dans le titre. Mais j'ai quand même deux sous-questions.

**Q1 -**  Quelle est la différence entre ces deux termes ? (et qu'est-ce qui pourrait motiver cette différence sur le plan étymologique ou historique…)

**Q2 -** J'ai même des collègues qui parlent de prédiction pour désigner l'estimation (dans le présent) du rayonnement solaire. Pour moi ces deux termes concernent le futur, est-ce que je me trompe ?

**Mon avis sur Q1.**  Le même problème a priori se pose en anglais (*prediction* et *forecasting*) mais je ne suis pas certain qu'il y ait une correspondance. Mon avis plutôt intuitif (intuition qui est le résultat du temps que j'ai passé vainement à chercher la réponse) est qu'il y a des consensus par communauté mais que ceux-ci ne coïncident pas nécessairement, voire sont opposés. Les consensus étant du type « A est approximatif alors que B est quantitatif ».

Par exemple, les météorologues de la télé utilisent le mot « prévision », mais les modèles numériques utilisés en anglais se dénomment « *Numerical Weather Prediction model* », par contre il y a tout un tas de journaux et de communautés du « *forecasting* » mais pas de la « *prediction* ». Les statisticiens français sauf s'ils sont météorologues n'utilisent pas le mot « prévision ». D'ailleurs une voyante fait des prévisions… Recenser tout cela et faire une étude conditionnée sur google refléterait à mon avis l'absence de structure :) Bref je suis un peu perdu !

Comment: Quant à moi, je dirais qu'une voyante fait des *prédictions*... pas des prévisions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Une [prédiction](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/prediction), c'est principalement l'action d'annoncer ce qui se passera dans le futur et par métonymie ce qui est prédit — quelle que soit la manière dont on a déterminé ces choses.

Une [prévision](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/prevision), c'est principalement le processus qui de détermination de l'évolution d'une situation, et par extension le résultat de cette évolution — quelle que soit la manière dont on détermine cette évolution.

Donc la différence principale des sens étendus (qui me semblent plus communs que les sens primaires et qui font l'objet de ta question), c'est qu'une prévision est une prédiction qui est considérée comme résultat de l'évolution de la situation présente.

Comment: Merci, je n'avais pas perçu cette distinction, c'est très clair et çà me semble juste. J'attends un peux et j'accepte !

Answer (score 8):

Si tu en restes à la construction des mots, les deux mots viennent respectivement des verbes *prédire* et *prévoir*, soit *pré-dire* et *pré-voir*, et donc *dire avant* ou *voir avant*.

Larousse :

> Prédire : Action d'annoncer par avance.
>
> Prévoir : Penser, d'après certaines données, qu'un fait futur est très probable.

Personnellement, une prédiction a une connotation un peu paranormale, tandis que prévision est plus pragmatique/scientifique.
Je parlerais donc de la prédiction d'un prophète, ou de la prévision d'un scientifique (voire d'un économiste).

Answer (score 1):

Et pourtant, nous lisons les prévisions des bulletins météorologiques et les prédictions des annuaires des marées conçus, en France, par les militaires (une situation un peu éloignée du monde de la voyance).

Je suis donc toujours un peu perdu.

Il me semble que prédire ou prévoir visent un même résultat, résultat dont la validité n'existera que dans le temps futur.  Si je veux appuyer la démonstration de ma prévision, j'utilise l'observation (ou plutôt l'analyse d'une grande masse d'observations), si je souhaite démontrer ma prédiction, j'utilise le langage (en sciences cette *langue* s'appelle les mathématiques, quand, face à une boule de cristal, j'utilise toutes les ambiguïtés du vocabulaire de la langue vernaculaire, langue moins précise donc beaucoup plus aléatoire).

Je ne suis pas encore convaincu...